# get string from file name using KSH

Tags: ksh

I have a file name like 'XXAR_CUST_INV_pt_PT_BURST.xml'.
I need only "BURST" as result.

note: file name can have many "_"'s (Underscores). So, I need string from last underscore and before extension ".xml" which "BURST"

```
s="XXAR_CUST_INV_pt_PT_BURST.xml"
BUSRTING='';
source <(sed -r 's/(.*)_([^_]*)[.].*/BUSRTING="\1"/' <<< "${s}")
# Result:
BUSRTING=$(printf '%s' "$BUSRTING" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')
echo BUSRTING=$BUSRTING"
```

expected result is BURST

```
s="XXAR_CUST_INV_pt_PT_BURST_US.xml"
BUSRTING='';
source <(sed -r 's/(.*)_([^_]*)[.].*/BUSRTING="\1"/' <<< "${s}")
# Result:
BUSRTING=$(printf '%s' "$BUSRTING" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')
echo BUSRTING=$BUSRTING"
```

expected result is US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BURSTING=${s%.xml}         # cut off extension
BURSTING=${BURSTING##*_}   # cut off anything before the last underscore
typeset -u BURSTING        # make uppercase
```

Comment: Thank You. and How do I get the rest of the left string like XXAR_CUST_INV_pt_PT?

Comment: @ArunGoWdA echo "${s%_*}"

Comment: It's `typeset -u` in ksh88 and ksh93 as well (and `zsh`, though `zsh` also has `${(U)BURSTING}`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas hmm, the pdksh manpage insists that `-u` is “unsigned” in AT&T ksh, though probably only in combination with `-i`…

Comment: Yes, `-u` is unsigned with `-i`, and uppercase without, there's no -U there. zsh has -U for _unique_. [The NetBSD sh maintainer was suggesting `local -U` to create a local variable initially unset](http://austingroupbugs.net/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=767#c3737) to conciliate ash-based shells where `local` only affects the scope and otherwise keeps the value and attributes of variables and `mksh` whose `unset` can't be used on local variables.

Comment: Yes, [that was noted later on in the discussion](http://austingroupbugs.net/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=767#c3741)